# Accessing properties of a dynamic object returned by facebook sdk api

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm fetching some data from FB using the following code:

```
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.ids = "me";
    parameters.fields = "friends";
    dynamic result = fbApp.Api(parameters);

    foreach (dynamic item in result)
    {
        Response.Write("<h1>" + item.name + "</h1>");
    }
```

This code fails, apparently the property name cannot be accessed, here's the error:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>' does not contain a definition for 'name'
```

What i'm doing wrong when accessing the properties? Isn't this the correct way to do so?

The query returns the info i want, just can't access it. Query in the browser is returning:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "John Doe 1 ",
         "id": "123456789"
      },
      {
         "name": "John Doe 1 ",
         "id": "123456789"
      },
      {
         "name": "John Doe 1 ",
         "id": "123456789"
      }
   ]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a key value pair sto try item.Value!

Comment: Yes, but that its not the way I want to get the info. I want to get it in the same way that is in this getting started sample http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=QuickStart%20using%20the%20API&referringTitle=Documentation#CommentsAnchor Which is using the dynamic object.property_name

Comment: Well, you're right! I tried and worked. I just don't remember to see this ever in any example. Thanks a lot Iraklis!